# What's this flat squiggly line below the notes at the end of this clarinet jazz solo?

Tags: notation, jazz, woodwinds, ornaments, clarinet

This is from cuphead.
Youtube link here:

It kind of sounds like vibrato.

Comment: More interesting to me is the use of the rest signs in bars 25, 26 and 27.

Comment: @Tim it's flamenco rhythm observing the grouping of straight 4/4.

Comment: @phoog - I thought 4/4 timing needed the bar to be divided into 2 halves. With a crotchet rest instead of two quaver rests, it would still do just that.

Comment: @Tim it's not universal practice, of course, but modern notational style avoids quarter rests starting on the offbeat.  I find it really confusing here, though, because it makes the first 3/8 of the measure look different from the second 3/8 of the measure when it would be better for them to look similar.  Not only are the rests different, but also the amount of horizontal space.  Very confusing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a horse-like whinny.  Like the one the trumpet does in 'Sleigh Ride'.

Or here's another clarinet example:

The wavy line is pretty descriptive, but doesn't specifically notate that effect. You'd need a few words of instruction as well.

Comment: Thanks. Would you have any idea on how to do that on clarinet?